# ContentAdapter using JSON Data in Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

The android app i am working on has tabs navigation using fragments

I have a ContentAdapter in my fragment activity/view that uses data from the res/values/arrays.xml (as below) to render the tabs content

**res/values/arrays.xml**

```
<resources>
  <string-array name="names">
    <item>an item A</item>
    <item>an item B</item>
  </string-array>
  <string-array name="descs">
    <item>this is desc for item A</item>
    <item>this is desc for item B</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

**java/my.app.namespace/MyFragmentList.java Adapter**

```
public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    // Set numbers of List in RecyclerView.
    private static final int LENGTH = 18;

    private final String[] mDesc;
    private final String[] mName;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context) {

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        mDesc = resources.getStringArray(R.array.descs);
        mName = resources.getStringArray(R.array.names);

        a.recycle();
    }
```

I can see that inside public ContentAdapter() the resources file is called and values are set for later access in the public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) which renders each item in the xml.

I want to access an external JSON URL inside the public ContentAdapter(Context context) and set the array values from there.

```
public ContentAdapter(Context context) {

        //Resources resources = context.getResources();
        //mDesc = resources.getStringArray(R.array.descs);
        //mName = resources.getStringArray(R.array.names);

        //get JSON URL Data (ASYNC?)
        mName = set name from json;
        //...

        a.recycle();
    }
```

Not sure what the best way would be fetching the JSON at this point in the application. Do I download the JSON before loading the MainActivity or do I do the JSON fetching at this point?

Comment: You should not load data inside adapter, first you should load/fetch in your respective activity/fragment and pass reference to adapter.
So First fetch your json data in activity, parse it there and than pass the result list to adapter.

Comment: What if my activity is actually accessed via setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {} in main activity..

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment:

> You should not load data inside adapter, first you should load/fetch in your respective activity/fragment and pass reference to adapter. So First fetch your json data in activity, parse it there and than pass the result list to adapter.

You should follow below approach:

In your activity:

```
private class GetContentTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

    public GetContentTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // fetch JSON from api
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        //you can pass string or json object whatever is preferred
        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //show progress
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //hide progress
        ArrayList<String> mDesc; // parse array from result
        ArrayList<String> mName; // parse array from result

        //set your adapter
        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(context,mDesc,mName);

        //or call your method and pass data in it
        setupViewPager(viewPager,mDesc,mName);
    }
}
```

Your adapter class:

```
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<String> mDesc;
    private final ArrayList<String> mName;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> mDesc,ArrayList<String> mName) {
        this.mDesc = mDesc;
        this.mName = mName;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.